# DataGridView Row Enter

Tags: c#

I am trying to determine if the user has selected a row to get the currently selected row. But when the form is initialized it calls the event.

Is there a way to check if the data grid view is being initialized? I thought about setting a flag and using RowPostPaint to set the flag.

Any other ways to ignore the select row event during initialization?

Comment: How are you doing it and what do you want to achive?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to check if the DataGridView has the focus:

```
if (this.dataGridView.Focused)
{
    // handle selection ...
}
```

On form initialization the control shouldn't have the focus but when the user manually changes the row selection it should have the focus.

And maybe you are using the wrong event to determine the row selection. Are you using "RowEnter"? I suggest you use "SelectionChanged" and then access the "SelectedRow" property.

Answer (score -1):

It depends to which event you subscribe, I suppose it's SelectionChanged ?
If so - define some boolean variable (like dgvIsInitialized), set it false by default, then load data into datagridview datasource and - after loading - set it true.
And in SelectionChanged event do similar to this:

```
if (dgvIsInitialized)
    MessageBox.Show("Selection changed");
```